# Python asyncio + websockets - first connection always fails, all others succeed

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm working on learning asyncio and websockets. On the very first client connection, the server throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 236, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self)
  File "/home/jdm/code/radio/Allmon3/src/./allmon3", line 322, in node_status_handler
    async for message in ws_broadcaster:
  File "/home/jdm/code/radio/Allmon3/src/asl/WebsocketBroadcaster.py", line 16, in subscribe
    value, waiter = await waiter
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<WebSocketServerProtocol.handler() running at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py:236>> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

However after that, every subsequent connection works perfectly, gets all the data, and works as expected with no errors. The application is based carefully on the websockets broadcast "pub-sub" model. Here's what I believe to be the relevant code (lots of stuff chopped out for readability):

```
# Websocket handler
async def node_status_handler(websocket):
    log.debug("entering node_status_handler for {}".format(websocket.remote_address))
    ws_connections.add(websocket)
    try:
        async for message in ws_broadcaster:
            await websocket.send(message)

    except asyncio.exceptions.IncompleteReadError:
        log.info("Other side went away: {}".format(websocket.remote_address))
        pass

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError:
        log.info("ConnctionClosed with Error from {}".format(websocket.remote_address))
        ws_connections.remove(websocket)

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
        log.info("ConnctionClosed from {}".format(websocket.remote_address))
        ws_connections.remove(websocket)

# Websocket broadcaster
async def node_status_broadcast(asl, log):
    log.debug("enter node_status_broadcast()")
    last_db_update = time.time()
    asl_ok = True
    while True:

      ## omitted - all the logic is here

# Primary node function
async def node_status_main(asl, log):
    log.debug("enter node_status_main()")

    async with websockets.serve(
        node_status_handler,
        host = None,
        port = WS_PORT,
        logger = log,
        compression = None,
        ping_timeout = None
    ):
        await node_status_broadcast(asl, log)
# Execute the main status gathering loop
log.debug("starting the main work loop")

ws_connections = set()
ws_broadcaster = WebsocketBroadcaster.WebsocketBroadcaster()

try:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        asyncio.run(node_status_main(asl, log))
        log.debug("run?")
finally:
    log.debug("Clean up on aisle 5")
```

The `WebsocketBroadcaster` is a class that's basically [this class](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/broadcast.html#publishsubscribe).

I've tried moving ws_broadcaster out of the global scope and into node_status_main() but that breaks all connections. I feel like I'm missing something simple but I've been poking at this and trying to do searches about this for days. Running the websockets test code works fine obviously.

### Solution

In case anyone ever stumbles across this, the solution was to add a setter function to the WebsocketBroadcaster class that would accept a replacement Future object for the one created in `__init__` and create a new `asyncio.Future()` object with the loop from inside the run():

```
def set_waiter(self, Future):
    self.waiter = Future
```

```
async def node_status_main(asl, log):
    log.debug("enter node_status_main()")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ws_broadcaster.set_waiter(asyncio.Future(loop=loop))
    async with websockets.serve(
        node_status_handler,
        host = None,
        port = WS_PORT,
        logger = log,
        compression = None,
        ping_timeout = None
    ):
        await node_status_broadcast(asl, log)
```

It seems that the waiter was getting set properly after the first, failed execution.